# How to find window ID in a REMOTE linuix

Tags: linux, x11

I connect to a remote linux using ssh and I need to get only a window with x11vnc, i.e., I need to execute:

x11vnc -id  -display :0

Every command I try in the ssh session (xprop, wmcrtl, etc.) returns info about the local xwindows system, not about the remote one, so I don't know how to get information of the windows running in the remote machine.

I can't get the while desktop with x11vnc because it is locked and I get only a black screen. I would try the '-id pick' option if had access to the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

> Every command I try in the ssh session (xprop, wmcrtl, etc.) returns info about the local xwindows system, not about the remote one

I assume this is because you connect using `ssh -X` or something similar. That way ssh sets `DISPLAY` to point to a tunnel it created to your local X server so that remote commands can display output on your screen. Try to override this variable, examples: `DISPLAY=:0 xwininfo -tree -root` or `DISPLAY=:0 xprop -root|grep ^_NET_CLIENT_LIST`.

Comment: DISPLAY=:0 did the trick even when connecting with ssh -X. Thanks.